# Is it possible to switch all exceptions to generic messages?

Tags: java, configuration

In Java, is it possible to force all exceptions to return a generic message? 
(that is, uncaught exceptions.)

Context: When testing applications, I often encounter applications which leak information through exceptions. I would like to recommend a way to force exceptions to give a generic message.

Example: Give bad input to application. Application dies, giving error message from exception.

Comment: try/catch {Exception e} around your main method?

Comment: Maybe by using `Thread.setUncaughtExceptionHandler()`... Note however that if you use thread pools, you'll have to repeat that for each of them

Comment: I like those two. I'm not sure how palatable the try/catch idea would be in a larger app.

Comment: What kind of application do you have?

Comment: I test large Java web apps. This is a recurring issue I see.

Answer (score 0):

The most generic way is:

```
try { ... } catch (Throwable t) { ... };
```

Sometimes I use this method when there is an exception generated and I don't know where it comes from.